# Get last position known in foreground Android

Tags: java, android, location

After several (unsuccessful) attempts to make my applications compliant about the background access to the location, I decided to re-structure my code in order to remove the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission from the `manifest`.

My `application` necessarily needs to get the location of the device at certain times (specifically I need the coordinates), what I'm interested in knowing is:
without using the permission mentioned above, how do I get, **in foreground**, the location of the device?

is it possible to do it with a one-time call without using services etc?

I thought about using this code, do you think it could be enough?

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
 mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
 mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
    .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {
                // Logic to handle location object
            }
        }
    });
```

or something like this:

```
        LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || location.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                bestLocation = location;
            }
        }
```

is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you do not request current location when the app is in background, then it's good enough.

Comment: i need in Foreground

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the last know location you need to have following permissions declared in Manifest file.

> "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

Then you may use Fused Location Provider as you have used.

Now if you want periodic updates you may want to register for those updates using following callback.

> requestLocationUpdates

passed with a request object and callback to receive updates.

Helpful links with exact code: [Request Updates](https://developer.android.com/training/location/request-updates)